# Applying Bayes: Estimating a bimodal distribution

Tags: distributions, bayes

I'm trying to estimate a bunch of bimodal distributions, i.e. two means and two standard deviations, based on a variable number of inputs. If no input is present, a constant value should be returned. From my anecdotal knowledge of what Bayes is about, this should be exactly it, no? Adapt a prior based on incoming evidence. My question is, though, how would I go about that in detail? Maybe I'm just missing a good tutorial somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### EM algorithm

In response to @Daniel Johnson, I want to quickly show you how you can fit the EM algorithm in `R`. Use the package [`mixtools`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/index.html) ([click for a link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/index.html)). Then, you can use the `normalmixEM` function with the option `k=2` to estimate the parameters of a two-component gaussian mixture distribution. Let's make an example:

```
# Let's look at the old faithful data

library(mixtools)

data(faithful)
plot(density(faithful$waiting), las=1, col="steelblue", lwd=2, main="")
```

[image: Old faithful waiting time]

The distribution is clearly bimodal, so we're gonna calculate a mixture model with 2 components (`k=2`):

```
out <- normalmixEM(faithful$waiting, k=2, epsilon = 1e-03, fast=TRUE)

summary(out)    

summary of normalmixEM object:
          comp 1    comp 2
lambda  0.361283  0.638717
mu     54.628096 80.099412
sigma   5.882584  5.859425
loglik at estimate:  -1034.002
```

The first normal distribution has an estimated mean of $54.6$ with a standard deviation of $5.88$, the second a mean of $80.1$ with a standard deviation of $5.86$. This corresponds nicely to the peaks in the graph above.

---

### Bayesian methods

To estimate the mixture models with Bayesian methodology, use the `bayesmix` package for `R` ([click here for link](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/bayesmix/index.html)). You'll need to install [JAGS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/) on your computer first, though (just download the exectuble file and install it). To illustrate its use, I re-run the above example of old faithful data. I choose independent (option `independence`) and uninformative priors (option `priorsUncertain`). Further, we run 10000 MCMC samples (option `n.iter=10000`) and discard the first 1000 as burn-in samples (option `burn.in=1000`):

```
library(bayesmix)

data(faithful)

bayesmod <- BMMmodel(faithful$waiting, k=2, priors=list(kind = "independence", parameter = "priorsUncertain", hierarchical = NULL)) # k=2 for two components

jcontrol <- JAGScontrol(variables = c("mu", "tau", "eta", "S"), burn.in = 1000, n.iter = 10000, seed = 10)

z <- JAGSrun(faithful$waiting, model = bayesmod, control = jcontrol, tmp = FALSE, cleanup = TRUE)

zSort <- Sort(z, by = "mu")

zSort
```

The model output is ("mu" denotes the estimates of the means and "sigma2" the estimates of the variances):

```
Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output:
Start = 1001 
End = 11000 
Thinning interval = 1 

 Empirical mean, standard deviation and 95% CI for eta 
         Mean     SD   2.5%  97.5%
eta[1] 0.3622 0.0318 0.3013 0.4251
eta[2] 0.6378 0.0318 0.5749 0.6987

 Empirical mean, standard deviation and 95% CI for mu 
       Mean     SD  2.5% 97.5%
mu[1] 54.63 0.7365 53.25 56.12
mu[2] 80.08 0.5128 79.02 81.05

 Empirical mean, standard deviation and 95% CI for sigma2 
           Mean    SD  2.5% 97.5%
sigma2[1] 36.11 7.209 24.61 52.76
sigma2[2] 35.38 5.066 26.90 46.34
```

The estimated means are $54.63$ and $80.08$ with standard deviations (square roots of the variances "sigma2") of $\sqrt(36.11)\approx 6.01$ and $\sqrt(35.38)\approx 5.95$. This is very close to the estimates we've calculated with `normalmixEM`.

Answer (score 1):

I think "[A Gentle Tutorial of the EM Algorithm
and its Application to Parameter
Estimation for Gaussian Mixture and
Hidden Markov Models](http://melodi.ee.washington.edu/people/bilmes/mypapers/em.pdf)" is exactly what you're looking for. Particularly the third section: Finding Maximum Likelihood Mixture Densities Parameters via EM.

Comment: thanks. not sure I want to see the non-gentle introduction though :)